# Post from PouchDB to CouchDB via IIS ARR reverse proxy ends with 502.3 (Bad Gateway)

Tags: javascript, iis, proxy, couchdb, pouchdb

When I make a `POST` request to `IIS` reverse proxy which redirects to `CouchDB` without any data, I get `400 Bad Request` as a response. This is expected and correct.

However, when I make the same `POST` with `POST` data included, I get `502.3 Bad Gateway` `0x80072efe` `ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_ABORTED`. This is not expected. I should get `400 Bad Request` back.

Here is log comparison of the two calls. First is `POST with data`, second is `POST without data`.

https://www.diffchecker.com/vkwnbear

Do you know why this happens?

Background: `PouchDB` calls `_bulk_get` on `CouchDB` through `IIS` `ARR` reverse proxy. `_bulk_get` does not exist and should return `400 Bad Request` which is then handled by `PouchDB`.